# Having multiple event listeners on one button JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

So I'm working on a project and was wondering how to put multiple listeners on one button. I want to be able to setText of certain text fields and start the game in one button press. However, the text fields aren't updated until the game finishes. ( I only put the code I thought was relevant, which the button press, I only put in one case from the switch since they're pretty similar).
I was thinking that if the button could have multiple event listeners, it could run two separate methods to set text fields and play the game in one click. The input comes from a different event listener.

```
  private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    /**Prompts the user for their name*/
    System.out.println("What is your name?: ");
    /**Plays the game*/
    if((Hyd > 0 && Hung > 0) && (Temp > 0 && Rest > 0)){
    try{

        Deck cards = new Deck();


        cardNum =  ((int)(Math.random() * 5) + 1);;

        /**Plays a specific card method depending on the randomly generated number*/
        switch (cardNum)
        {
            case 1: question = ("You've run into a bear!");
                    greenChoice = ("Green Button: You RUN away!");
                    redChoice = ("Red Button: You FIGHT the bear!");
// i want to change this textfield as soon as the button is clicked
                               questionK.setText(question);
                    System.out.println("(Hold the button you choose until the game replies)");

                    /**Count down timer for the user*/
                    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Timer: " + i);
                        Thread.sleep(i * 350);
                    }
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. (Spoiler: 1) Remove the `Thread.sleep(..)`. 2) Use a Swing `Timer` to schedule updates.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
You do not need two listeners. The `startActionPerformed` method can respond differently based on `cardNum` as you did. The problem is that  if `startActionPerformed` (or any other method on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) ) is long (like `Thread.sleep(i * 350)`) , the GUI becomes unresponsive (freezes) and is updated only when this process ends. For more help please post [mcve]

Comment: i used the swing timer and it worked, thanks.